# OpenGL: How to draw a triangle or polygon smoothly

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

I'm drawing a triangle using polygonmode as below:

```
drawScene(void)
{
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glShadeModel(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glVertex3f(x1,y1,z1);
        glVertex3f(x2,y2,z2);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Vertices (x, y, z, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) are calculating using sin() and cos() and im passing into drawScene() method. Triangle is rotated based on the sin() and cos() values. My problem is, triangle is not smooth when it is drawn. That is, outer part of the triangle is not have a smooth line. In the above code instead of GL_FILL if I use GL_LINE triangle looks smooth. But, I need a filled triangle.

Comment: It looks like an aliasing problem. Could you please upload a screenshot of the issue so that we can better understand?

Comment: Please change the title of the question to indicate that you refer to drawing a smooth triangle and not to the motion of the triangle. Or clarify if I misunderstood

Comment: @dirk Using the calculated value of  sin() and Cos() im passing the values for the vertices in a loop and rotating the triangle. Based on that I draw the triangle. After drawing, the triangle does not have proper border. Sorry, If the question is still confusing. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Im not sure how to upload the image. I will try to upload ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the graphics card, anti-aliasing may not be avaliable, may be disabled, or may be application-controlled.

For example, take a look at this configuration page from a graphics card:

[image: NVidia CP]

So, in this case any 3D application will be aliased, since the user chooses to, and you can't/shouldn't go around that choice. Check your graphics card control panel/settings to see if it has such an option (it may not support anti-aliasing depending on its age).

Furthermore, please take some time writing a descriptive, ***accurate*** title for your questions or nobody here will pay you much attention.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the title properly. Will take care next time. Thanks for your reply. I verified my graphics card setting and it is of type [Intel Graphics Setting](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-030506.htm). Can you please tell me whether this supports antialiased?

Comment: I have no idea. I had a laptop that had an Intel Graphics card, the settings page was similar to that one (but had an anti-aliasing setting). IIRC, I disabled anti-aliasing because I cared more about performance, but do play with any setting that mentions anti-aliasing and see if it does something to graphics applications that use 3D. Oh, and remember to restart any application to see the changes (for example, changing graphics settings while a game is running sometimes has no effect until it is restarted).